# print_r with string concatenation

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to write the content of an Array to screen with `print_r`. The first snippet of code gives the correct output, but the second snippet of code that does the same thing with string concatenation displays the content of the Array on one line. Why is this?

> My code 1:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($mixed_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

> Result 1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => fox
    [2] => dog
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )

)
1
```

> My code 2:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($mixed_array)."</pre>";
```

> Result 2:

```
Printing Array: Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => fox [2] => dog [3] => Array ( [0] => x [1] => y [2] => z ) )

1
```

Comment: First syntactically its wrong and you should use `print_r` during array print. Check manual before asking please.

Answer (score 3):

Your first code opens `<pre>` tag, then outputs `$mixed_array` then do `echo 1` then closes `<pre>` tag.

Your second code calculates `"<pre>".print_r($mixed_array)."</pre>"` which triggers printing `$mixed_array` before `echo` and then it `echo <pre>1</pre>` which is result of calculation.

When you use `print_r($mixed_array)` you are triggering printing. It returns `TRUE` which is echoed as `1`. If you want to use information instead of printing it, you need to call `print_r($mixed_array, true)`. If you will set the second parameter to `TRUE`, both your examples will have the same output:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($mixed_array, true);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>" . print_r($mixed_array, true) . "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 2):

you should not to `echo` any functions which print something on the creen like `print_r`. 
Code no. 1 should look like this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($mixed_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Notice there is no "echo" before "print_r".

Answer (score 1):

Check manual about `print_r`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

From manual:

> print_r() **displays** information about a variable in a way that's
>   readable by humans.

Displays, **not returning**. So you should not using `echo`; `print_r` is some kind of `echo`. But you can use `echo` with this function in some way, using second parameter:

> **If you would like to capture the output of print_r(), use the return
>   parameter**. When this parameter is set to TRUE, print_r() will return
>   the information rather than print it.

So if you do it like this:

```
$mixed_array = array("1" => "PHP code tester Sandbox Online",  
              "foo" => "bar", 5 , 5 => 89009, 
              "case" => "Random Stuff: " . rand(100,999),
              "PHP Version" => phpversion()
              );

echo "<pre>".print_r($mixed_array, true)."</pre>";
```

display will be like that:

```
Array
(
    [1] => PHP code tester Sandbox Online
    [foo] => bar
    [2] => 5
    [5] => 89009
    [case] => Random Stuff: 899
    [PHP Version] => 5.3.29
)
```